# Any app play VBR MP3 files?

Tags: audio, mp3, mp3-player

Does any Android app play Variable Bit Rate MP3 files,  while not demanding Internet access and access to my Contacts? I used soundconverter on my Xubuntu PC to convert MP4 files to MP3 and they play OK using Audigy on the laptop, but don't have any sound output using either Google Music or the default sound player on my ver. 4.4.2 Samsung Galaxy Mega 6.3.

Answer (score 1):

VBR is not the problem here. I've had no problems playing VBR MP3 files in any music app.